# When compiling swf files in debug vs. release, what are the performance differences?

Tags: actionscript-3, performance, flash, compilation

Where can i find information on the differences between compiling a swf in release or in debug?  I would like to know about differences in terms of file size, memory consumption, and overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments...

The reason nobody has probably ever done stats on this is because the debug mode is only there for testing purposes. 
In other words: it doesn't really matter us if it's a bit slower and bigger as all we are really looking for is to have a reliable end product (i.e release version).

Note that the performance will also vary between players (activeX or not/player version/OS) so it would be almost impossible to nail down any precise numbers.

Maybe you can explain why you insist on having this information otherwise I suggest you do it your self within the interested context.

**To do so, plug a [FPS meter](http://code.google.com/p/mrdoob/wiki/stats) on a performance consuming project and compare the results.**

Let us know if you find out something relevant !

Thanks

T

Answer (score 0):

> different in file size different in memory consumption and over all ?

That is to be expected. Debug builds typically include:

- debug symbols and miscellaneous information
- special checks

So they are likely to be:

- slower
- use more memory

Read about [Build Phase](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/introbd_4.html) and more!

Comment: i wont to know numbers percentage ? it is obvious there is different

Comment: It will vary with the project you are working on. Test with a few different projects.

Comment: i am looking for same statistic number on this different

Comment: There probably isn't any in the public domain.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the loading of RSL libraries is notably slower when compiled with debug on.  Another notable "debug" slowdown is the loading of fonts from another swf.